# Unity Distance Calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to calculate the distance of the mouse from the player character so I can set up a bool based on the distance, but it starts the calculation from bottom left corner instead of the player character from what I can see with using debug.log.

```
if ((Vector3.Distance(playerCharacter.transform.position , Input.mousePosition)) <= maxMouseDistance)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: well mousePosition is in **screen space (=pixel)**, while your character is probably placed somewhere in the 3D world space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `mousePosition` to world space before calculating the distance. You can use the [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) function for this. You also need to add some depth information to your mouse position. Otherwise you will always get the same result.

```csharp
float depth = 1;//should be bigger than the camera nearClipPlane
Vector3 screenPoint = Input.mousePosition;
screenPoint.z = depth;
Vector3 worldPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
float dist = Vector3.Distance(playerCharacter.transform.position , worldPoint);
if(dist <= maxMouseDistance)
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Character and the grid I'm trying to interact is on z axis 0 but Even if I set the depth to 1 or any other number it just ignores it I guess because every debug I get back on .Distance starts from 10. Since I'm working on 2D top-down I'm just going to make it that we get player's location on the grid and add distance to this point to find maximum interactable grid cells.